# Blazor : Mudblazor : Container with Docker : CSS not loading?

Tags: css, docker, blazor

I have created a small application using Blazor and MudBlazor with the Blazor server hosting model.

I am working on Windows. The app is working when testing locally.

I have followed this blog [post](https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/containerizing-blazor-apps/) to containerize my Blazor application. The container is running but all CSS is gone.

Anybody has an idea what needs to be modified for the CSS to be considered when moving from local host to local Docker container ?

Comment: Is it correct that you're using nginx to serve the files?

Comment: No since this is not mentionned in the blog post for the "server" hosting mode. But perhaps something is missing from the post ? Because at the end they state `Configure NGINX or another reverse proxy for your Blazor Server applications` but this is not mentioned in the post content itself

Comment: As I read it, when they tell you how to create the Dockerfile, the first line is `FROM nginx`. The reason I ask is that there've been a lot of questions about nginx returning content type 'text/html' for css files lately which might be what you're experiencing. But if you're using the aspnet based Dockerfile, then that's probably not the same issue.

Comment: This is my Dockerfile (server hosting mode in the post) `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY artifacts/ app/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/servertest.dll"]` so no NGINX I suppose ?

Answer (score 0):

**Exclude bin and obj folder via dockerignore**
Excluding the *bin* and *obj* folders via the *.dockerignore*, should fix this issue.

Add in .dockerignore file:

```
# Exclude build artifacts
**/bin/
**/obj/
```

**NOTE:** Still after adding this, the problem might occur. You can then try the following:

**Clear docker build cache**
Docker might have cached some layers to. You can add *--no-cache* to the docker build to make sure no cached layers are used

```
docker build --no-cache {other docker build flags here}
```

**Think about browser cache** Also make sure that your browser cache is cleared (or open in browser incognito mode to make sure "old" css is not cached in the browser). This can easily be forgotten and then it still looks like the css is not loaded correctly.

**Clear local project info** If all of that did not work, you can also try to do a *clean* on your project/solution and delete the *obj and bin* folders of your WASM project.